# Is sameOriginDisabled and setAllowedOrigin("*") are for same purpose in spring websocket security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket

In Spring websocket security, I found options, which looks like similar, can anyone explain?

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-disable

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration.html#setAllowedOrigins-java.lang.String...-

```
sameOriginDisabled() vs setAllowedOrigins("*")
```

In my application, even though, I have setAllowedOrigin(*), if access websocket from a different domain (localhost:4200 -> app server), app is asking me to authenticate again. If I connect from the same domain (deployed in the same server), it is going through.

Due to version conflicts, I couldn't try sameOriginDisabled(). We are using 3.2.10 spring security version.

So even if we upgrade, not sure whether sameOriginDisabled() will help me.